# Java : Writing console output to file, Not working

Tags: java

I have written an app for port scanning and I want to write my console output to a file but a little problem occurred. "PrintStream" is not writing all console output to the file.
 For instance: code within `try` block which shows opened ports in the console does not write anything to the file,  but dead hosts in `catch` block are written.

My code:

```
public class start {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        for (int i = 5935; i < 10000; i++){
        new test(i);
        }

        PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("E:\\ports.txt"));
        System.setOut(printStream);
        printStream.flush();


    }
}


class test implements Runnable{

    static String host = "localhost";
    int t;
    Thread y;

    public test(int t2){
        t = t2;
        y = new Thread(this);
        y.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket(host, t);
            System.out.println("Port is alive - " + t);
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Port is dead... - " + t);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any `Exception` thrown?

Comment: You're never closing it?

Comment: 1. you never close any socket; 2. you never .join() your threads either. And 3. use an Executor, do not use Thread directly.

Comment: Try with `PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("E:\\ports.txt"), true);` to enable `autoFlush` when your data will contain line separator, like when you use `println`.

Comment: You are also starting your threads before redirecting the output.

Comment: You should set standard error output also to the file. `System.setErr();`

Comment: @UdayShankar There is no error output here.

Comment: @mlk that was just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues directly related to the issue at hand.

1. You set the output AFTER you have started the threads so where the output goes is almost random.
2. You don't wait for the threads to finish, so the application "just ends" at a random point.
3. You don't flush the output.

Updated code:

```
class StartPortTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        // Set up the stream BEFORE starting threads
        // This should be in a try-with-resources, or the close done in a finally block.
        PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("ports.txt"));
        System.setOut(printStream);

        // Start the threads!    
        List<PortTester> testers = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 5935; i < 10000; i++){
            testers.add(new PortTester(i));
        }

        // Wait for the threads to end
        for(PortTester t : testers ) {
            t.y.join();
        }

        // Flush (write to disk) and close.
        printStream.flush();
        printStream.close();;
    }
}


class PortTester implements Runnable{

    static String host = "localhost";
    int t;
    Thread y;

    public PortTester(int t2){
        t = t2;
        y = new Thread(this);
        y.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            // You should close this either in the finally block or using a try-with-resource. 
            Socket socket = new Socket(host, t);
            System.out.println("Port is alive - " + t);
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Port is dead... - " + t);
        }

    }
}
```

This is not perfect as

- it creates a ton of threads andit would be much better to use a thread pool.
- It also waits forever for the thread to finish, you might want it to only wait *x* seconds before giving up.
- Exceptions would cause the file to not be flushed & closed.
- You mix up presentation with logic. I'd NOT write System.out in the `PortTester`, but create a data structure describing the ports statuses and then output that after (separate presentation from logic).
- At the moment the ordering of the output is random (based on when the threads finish).

Comment: This code is not exception safe, e.g. does not close the printStream and socket on exception.

Comment: @wdk The sockets are never closed (other than via finalization or app termination)  Bad practise sure, but not the end of the world for this sort of application. The PrintStream will always be closed as it never throws exceptions (except if the join throws an interrupted exception). So the question is do I change lots of code and risk the OP not "seeing the forest for the trees", or have not great code that shows the issues the OP is having...

Comment: I know. But this seems a junior question, so better to show it the right way before in a real program he got all kind of resource leaks.

Answer (score 0):

- Close socket
- Use Executor Service
- Set output stream before writing output
- Wait for all jobs to be ready
- Flush output when ready
- Close printStream

Results in:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class start
{

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    try (PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("E:\\ports.txt"))) {
        System.setOut(printStream);

        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for (int i = 5935; i < 10000; i++) {
            final int port = i;
            pool.execute(() -> {
                try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", port)) {
                    System.out.println("Port is alive - " + port);
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Port is dead... - " + port);
                }
            });
        }
        pool.awaitTermination(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        printStream.flush();
    }
  }
}
```